# Server picking up old files

Tags: php, file, caching, server

I'm still inexperienced as a web developer so I have exhausted my knowledge on my current problem.

I recently made changes to files on my one website and uploaded them via FTP to the server. When I go to the website it's still executing the old code.

I cleared all my cache and tried on different devices. Even after changing the file names for example "logout.php" to "logout_code.php" as well as link references to those names when I click on the logout button it still goes to "logout.php".

Can anybody shed some light?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting a no-cache header on the page that redirects to the logout page.

```
        header('Expires: Sun, 01 Jan 2014 00:00:00 GMT');
        header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
        header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', FALSE);
        header('Pragma: no-cache');
```

The above snippet goes at the top of the page before any other output is sent. (within a `<?php  ?>` tag of course)

Comment: Thanks this did it.